# What is this disease or nutrient difficiency on my Parfianka Pomegranate?

Tags: nutrients, pomegranate

I've had a 3 foot tall Parfianka Pomegranate tree planted in the ground for several months. It gets about 7 hours of direct sunlight per day. It's been fertilized with compost, mycorrhizae enriched 10-10-10 fertilizer, and slow release fertilizer (In different months). I'm watering it deeply once a week. The leaves aren't browning, so I didn't think it needed that more water.

It has barely grown - just a few leaves here and there. I noticed that the color of the leaves are pale green, even white on the tips. Many of the leaves also have faint gray dots.

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, I have a Wonderful pomegranate of the same age growning nearby that has been doing stupendously. It's leaves are a deep forest green, it's creating many thick branches, and it's even flowering. The difference in care is that the Wonderful was grown in a pot in the beginning, whereas the Parfianka was immediately planted in the ground upon receiving it. The Wonderful is using Miracle-Gro soil, which is was more "soil-like" (dark black and mushy), while the Parfianka is using Kellogg soil (less composted, wood chippy).

This is a photo of the Wonderful. It's a little hard to compare because the lighting is different, but the Wonderful is definitely bushier, greener, and thicker.

[image]

Comment: Important: What is the pH of the soil?

Comment: @J.Musser I have no idea. I should really but a PH meter...

Comment: I'm assuming you'd notice scale, or other stem/leaf pests. Did you check for root mealybugs? If there's nothing apparently wrong with the top, look at the roots. If you notice anything abnormal, post it.

Comment: I see no bugs on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably that horrid Kellog stuff - I seem to recall you had problems with another plant growing in it. Optimum ph for pomegranate is 6.5-7, but they will grow in more acidic and less acidic soils too, they're not too fussy, but what they can't stand is poorly drained soil.

It has the appearance of nutrient shortage, maybe nitrogen, but you've said you've been fertilising. Cercospora fruit spot can cause greyish spotting on leaves, but inspect the plant for signs of other problems such as thrips, whitefly, mealybug or scale insect. The other possibility is trouble at the roots if the soil is not free draining, but if you can't find anything obvious, I'd be inclined to dig it up and pot it in something decent until its got bigger and to see if it recovers.

Comment: I agree! Drainage!! Raise your beds by double digging and get rid of the bark! That stuff is feeding the decomposers, not your plants.  Just raising the beds by 6" makes all the difference for roots. The white tips are an indication of high salts. Poor drainage. If your plants aren't thriving then you'll get infestations. But the problem is DRAINAGE. Roots are only in the top 6" primarily.  So easy to raise beds!  One time of double digging and that's it.  Quit using bark!!